# Comparing one field of file1 to other field of file2 in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two files file 1 and file 2. I want to see first column of file1 and go to that line number in file2.After that I am comparing $2 of file1  with $6 of file2. If matches then print "correct ans".I want to do this using awk.

**file1.txt**

```
1,B
3,C
2,A
```

**file2.txt**

```
Html,WeB,title,tech,Laravel,B
Html,WeB,title,tech,Laravel,D
Html,WeB,title,tech,Laravel,C
```

**Output.txt**

```
Question  1 is correct
Question 3 is correct
Question 2 is incorrect
```

I have tried to do this.

```
awk -F[","] 'NR==FNR{n=$1;b=$2}
  {if( NR==$1 && $6==b){printf "Question n is        correct "}
  else { printf "Question n is incorrect"}}' myfile rahulque
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{ans[NR]=$6;next} {print "Question",$1,"is",((ans[$1]==$2)?"":"in")"correct";}' file2.txt file1.txt
Question 1 is correct
Question 3 is correct
Question 2 is incorrect
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{ans[NR]=$6;next}`

  For each line of the first file listed, `file2.txt`, we store the correct answer, `$6`, in an array `ans` with the line number, `NR`, as the key.  Then, we tell awk to skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `print "Question",$1,"is",((ans[$1]==$2)?"":"in")"correct"`

  For every line of the second listed file, `file1.txt`, we print whether or not the answer for question `$1` matches the correct answer specified in array `a`.

  In more detail, let's look at the ternary statement:

  ```
  (ans[$1]==$2)?"":"in"
  ```

  The answer is correct if `ans[$1]==$2`.  In that case, the ternary statement returns an empty string.  If the answer is incorrect, the ternary statement returns the string `in`.  The string returned by the ternary statement is placed in front of the string `correct` to form the desired word.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen a part of file2.txt, the list of correct answers, is kept in memory.  If the OP's tests were so long that the list of answers would not fit in memory, then we could look for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I always found `awk` confusing so if I were to find a solution to this question I'd avoid `awk` all to together and just write a shell script like ...

```
#!/bin/sh

sort file1.txt | cut -d, -f2 > /tmp/file1.cut
cut -d, -f6 file2.txt > /tmp/file2.cut

count=0
while read -r a && read -r b <&3
do
        count=`expr $count + 1`
        if [ $a == $b ]
        then
                echo  "Question $count is correct"
        else
                echo  "Question $count is incorrect"
        fi
done < /tmp/file1.cut 3< /tmp/file2.cut
```

... this seems to work with the sample data your provided.

```
$ cat file1.txt
1,B
3,C
2,A
$ cat file2.txt
Html,WeB,title,tech,Laravel,B
Html,WeB,title,tech,Laravel,D
Html,WeB,title,tech,Laravel,C
$ ./correct.sh
Question 1 is correct
Question 2 is incorrect
Question 3 is correct
$ cat correct.sh
#!/bin/sh

sort file1.txt | cut -d, -f2 > /tmp/file1.cut
cut -d, -f6 file2.txt > /tmp/file2.cut

count=0
while read -r a && read -r b <&3
do
        count=`expr $count + 1`
        if [ $a == $b ]
        then
                echo  "Question $count is correct"
        else
                echo  "Question $count is incorrect"
        fi
done < /tmp/file1.cut 3< /tmp/file2.cut
```

I sure there is a better way to do this, like using awk, but I think the shell script approach is more flex able.  For example if you wanted to count the number of incorrect and correct answers.